# Understanding takeWhile termination condition during Iterator.iterate in Scala

Tags: scala

I am having some trouble understanding why this code seemingly terminates early:

```
object intersectionDemo {
  val arr = Array(2, 4, 7, 8, 12, 20)
  val arr2 = Array(3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 20)
  Iterator.iterate((arr, arr2, List[Int]())) {
    case (one, two, res) =>
      if (one.head == two.head)
        (one.tail, two.tail, one.head :: res)
      else if (one.head > two.head)
        (one, two.tail, res)
      else
        (one.tail, two, res)
  }.takeWhile { case (a, b, _) => a.nonEmpty && b.nonEmpty }
    .toList.last._3.reverse
}
```

It returns `List(4, 8)` though it should return `List(4, 8, 20)` and if I inspect the first or second arrays here: `_._1` or `_._2` I get `Array(20)`. I do know there are other ways to solve the intersection of two arrays problem, I am just a little confused as to why the last element doesn't get inserted.

My guess is that it sees that `one.tail` and `two.tail` are `empty` and terminates the iteration, but shouldn't `one.head` get inserted still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it. (I'm using `List` syntax to demonstrate the `Array` status, but you get the idea.)

```
//   20::Nil     20::Nil       (Nil,      Nil,       20 :: 8 :: 4 :: Nil)
if (one.head == two.head) (one.tail, two.tail, one.head :: res)
```

The `20` gets inserted *when* `one` and `two` are emptied so if you `takeWhile` neither is empty then it hasn't been inserted yet.

If you change it to `.dropWhile{ ... }.next._3.reverse` then you get the results you're looking for.